# Is it possible to get the mnemonic phrase back, if I have a few private keys derived from this mnemonic phrase?

Tags: metamask, wallets, private-key

I used my mnemonic phrase to create a lot of accounts long time ago. I have the private keys of some account derived from this mnemonic phrase. Is there a possible way to find the mnemonic phrase back/find the private keys of all another account derived from this mnemonic phrase? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

a secret recovery phrase is generated using an hd wallet. Private keys are basically children of this phrase, but there's no way to go back to the parent having just the private key.